# Angular 6 routing on URL parameters

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am trying to configure Angular to route based on URL parameters

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { matcher: (url: UrlSegment[]) => {
     console.log(url);
     return url.length === 1 && url[0].path.indexOf('id=form') > -1 ? ({consumed: url}) : null;
  },
  component: FormComponent },
  { matcher: (url: UrlSegment[]) => {
     console.log(url);
     return url.length === 1 && url[0].path.indexOf('id=list') > -1 ? ({consumed: url}) : null;
  },
  component: ListComponent },
  { path: '**',  component: PageComponent }
];
```

A URL of `/worker?id=form&row=12345` should match the first route

A URL of `/worker?id=list` should match the second route

My issue is that inside my matcher the url.parameters is an empty object so I can't match on it.

Appreciate any help

Comment: you mean url[0].parameters is empty?

Comment: That's correct. Running Angular 6.0.2

Comment: Could you add a smal repro in stackblitz to toy around?

Comment: I created https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qsxuye Routing to /list and /form works. Routing to ?id=list and ?id=form does not and thats what I'm after. Thanks

Comment: I have logged an issue here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24093